# Dojo Horizontal range slider with 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider, range

I would like to have a horizontal range slider with the values displayed in two different input fields.
In the following source code presented in the website https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/RangeSlider.html the values are displayed only in one input field and are separated with comma(',') string

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, add the code directly to the question (without needing an external link) so people can understand what you want better. I would also add an extended explanation of what (and how) the codes does and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value property of the slider is an array, which contains both the value. You just need to populate the values in two different inputs instead of one. like below

```js
require(["dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(HorizontalRangeSlider, dojoDom){
  
  var rangeSlider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
    name: "rangeSlider",
    value: [2,6],
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 10,
    intermediateChanges: true,
    style: "width:300px;",
    onChange: function(value){
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMin").value = value[0];
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMax").value = value[1];
    }
  }, "rangeSlider");
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojox/form/resources/RangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="rangeSlider"></div>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMin" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMax" /></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to set the style to the slider but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: How can I set HorizontalRule and HorizontalRuleLabels? It shows just numbers but no graduated scale.

Comment: I'm sorry I've sloved it.